# print message on data insertion in database in oop

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I inserting a form data in mysql database using oop php in a pre made project.all work is coorrect but after submit any success and failed message is not showing.
my form sample code is:

performance.php->

```
   <h1>Employee Review Form</h1>
 <form name="product"  action="" method="post" id="customForm">
     <table>
          <tr>
         <td>Review Employee Id</td>
         <td><input type="text" name="rcode" id="rcode"  class="genInputBox" /></td>
     </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Domain Knowledge(Subject Matter)</td>
             <td><select name="dk" id="dk">
                     <option value="">Plz Select Ratting </option>
                     <option value="5">5</option>
                     <option value="4">4</option>
                     <option value="3">3</option>
                     <option value="2">2</option>
                     <option value="1">1</option>
                 </select></td>
         </tr>and more...............
          <input type="submit" value="register" id="submit" name="form_submit"/>
                    </td></tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
```

and form submit process

```
     <?php

      if(isset($_POST) && isset ($_POST["form_submit"])){
     $valArr=array("review_emp_id"=>$_POST['rcode'],"subject_matter"=>$_POST['dk']);
    $per_obj = new Performance();
    $per_obj->addPreformance($valArr, "employee_performance");


    }
     ?>
```

and my class performance page is:

```
             <?php 
   require_once("admin/includes/class_common_lib.php");
    require_once("class.userinfo.inc.php");

    class Performance extends DataAccess{

var $db_obj = null;
public function  __construct() {     //for database connectivity
    $this->db_obj = new DataAccess();
}

public function  addPreformance($key_values = array(), $table = null) {
    $this->db_obj->table_name = $table;
      $this->db_obj->addRecord($key_values);


   }
  }

   ?>
```

and in class common lib add record function code is:

```
                    // Function for Add Record
    function addRecord($key_values)
    {

        $cols="";
        $vals="";
        foreach($key_values as $key=>$value)
        {
            if ($key!="submit" and $key!="PHPSESSID" and $key!="image_name" and $key!="submit_button" and $key!="ext" and $key!="ext2" and $key!="img_name" and $key!="mode" and $value!="" and $key!="gpl" and $key!="ip1" and $key!="ip2" and $key!="ip3" and $key!="ip4"){
                $cols .= "`".$key."`,";
                is_string($value)? $vals .= "'".addslashes($value)."'," : $vals .= "'".$value."',";

            }
        }

        $cols = substr($cols, 0, -1);
        $vals = substr($vals, 0, -1);

        $insert_qry="insert into ". $this->table_name ."(". $cols .") values(". $vals .")";

        $r=mysql_query($insert_qry);
        $this->msg = (!$r) ? f_add_msg : s_add_msg;
        return $r;
    }
```

Its a very big project and I do all the process which is done previous by other person.

now I want to show msz of data is submit in database or not (success or failed)after submission of form.

and I found these line in config file

```
      define ("s_add_msg", "Record successfully added.");

     define ("f_add_msg", "Record not added. Please try again.&error=1");
```

I know its lengthy code, but I need to show what happens.
all function Is working correctly,but
how can I show success or failed message in performance.php page?please help

Comment: It's hard to see where it's going wrong from the code samples you've provided. The relevant status message is being set in the db object but there's no code after the call to addPerformance to tell how that message is being retrieved.

Comment: yes sir, I told that is a bis  and pre made project and I am doing some correction only

Answer (score 1):

It's common in programming to use the [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern in situations like this. Without seeing your entire codebase a quick fix for this might be to change your form submit like this:

```
<?php

  if(isset($_POST) && isset ($_POST["form_submit"])){
     $valArr=array("review_emp_id"=>$_POST['rcode'],"subject_matter"=>$_POST['dk']);
     $per_obj = new Performance();
     $per_obj->addPreformance($valArr, "employee_performance");

     $redirectLink = "someOtherUrl.php?m=" . urlencode( $per_obj->db_obj->msg );
     header( 'Location: ' . $redirectLink );
     die();
}
 ?>
```

This will redirect to the new URL you have specified where you should be able to retrieve the status message using $_GET['m'].

Eventually you'd want to handle this in a much cleaner way across the system but if you're just trying to fix legacy code that will at least get you started.